# Angular Azure Storage Blob Worker

Tags: angular, azure, azure-blob-storage, web-worker, jsdom

All,

I am trying to work with the "@azure/storage-blob" module inside a web worker running from an Angular 13 Application.

The web worker is being called by a service inside the angular app.  I am getting XML parsing errors in the Browser Console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: This library depends on the following DOM
> objects: ["document", "DOMParser", "Node", "XMLSerializer"] to parse
> XML, but some of these are undefined. You may provide a polyfill to
> make these globally available in order to support your environment.
> For more information, please refer to
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/js/web-workers.

The above weblink mentions adding support for DOM objects by installing JSDOM and using pollyfill.
So far I haven't managed to get anything to work with Angular.  Below is the code for the web worker that caused the error:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

const sasURL = environment.sasURL;
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sasURL);
const containerName = environment.containerName;

// List blobs inside a container
async function main() {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  let i = 1;
  let blobs = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
  for await (const blob of blobs) {
    console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }
}

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  main();
  postMessage(response);
});
```